# Winforms - Combobox autocomplete doesn't show items with the same name

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I have a combobox with autocomplete,

Some of my items have the same display name..
The autocomplete shows only the first one it finds...I need it to show everything that matches the text input and not just the first one.

All i can find online is people making custom autocomplete comboboxes.
all i need is for it to show all matches.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Not without making a custom combobox.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Last line say "Is that possible?"  Answer: No